# Exception in std::vector<>::emplace_back() safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, vector, emplace

What happens when an exception is thrown in `std::vector<>::emplace_back()`?

For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int bar) {
    if (bar == 4) throw std::exception("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

and

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foo_list;
foo_list.emplace_back(new Foo(3));
try {
  foo_list.emplace_back(new Foo(4));
} catch (std::exception error) {
  // How bad is it?
}
// Whats inside foo_list now?
```

I would expect the vector to just contain the first Foo object.

**Is this the case? And is this guaranteed by the standard?**

**And also: Could there be any memory leaks?**

Comment: emplace_back is not running when the exception is thrown...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back see yourself

Comment: You have to evaluate the function arguments before calling a function. The constructor throws first. emplace_back was never called.

Comment: @Kenny: That makes sense, its simpler than I thought! I'll accept it when put in an answer...

Comment: The title is kind of misleading because, as others pointed out, the exception actually happens before `emplace_back` gets called.

Comment: Feel free to change the title :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would expect the vector to just contain the first Foo object.
>
> **Is this the case? And is this guaranteed by the standard?**

Yes. The comments above already explained that `emplace_back` never even gets called because the `Foo` constructor throws while initializing the arguments for the function.

**But ...**

> **And also: Could there be any memory leaks?**

Yes, you are using the anti-pattern that I have described at [Inserting into a container of smart pointers with emplace_back(new X)](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#emplace-new) (also published in [Overload Journal #134 - August 2016](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2271)).

The problem happens when `emplace_back` needs to reallocate the vector and that fails due to running out of memory. The pointer passed into the function will be lost, and so you leak the `Foo` object. This can happen for the first insertion (where the `Foo` constructor doesn't throw):

```
foo_list.emplace_back(new Foo(3));
```

Never use `emplace_back` to insert raw pointers into a container of `unique_ptr`, instead use `make_unique`:

```
foo_list.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>(3));
```

Or if you have to use C++11 then construct the `unique_ptr` and insert or emplace that, not a raw pointer:

```
foo_list.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(3)));
```

This way the object is owned by a `unique_ptr` immediately, and so if an exception happens inside `emplace_back` the object will be destroyed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, and nice Journal by the way! I also didn't know about std::tie, for example. Very useful :)